# Can this bar chart style from Excel be recreated with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to have the lines linking each data block, like the attached screenshot from Excel.  Even better would be if the line could change color based on it's angle.  I can't seem to find anything in the documentation to create this style chart. Any ideas?

[image: Excel Line Linked Data]

[JSFiddle - Same Bar Chart (without connectors)](https://jsfiddle.net/glm2/2Luqb0pa/)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Row1', 'Row2']   
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Data1',
        data: [9, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'Data2',
        data: [12, 6]
    }, {
        name: 'Data3',
        data: [15, 7]
    }, {
        name: 'Data4',
        data: [16, 8]
    }, {
        name: 'Data5',
        data: [19, 7]
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: There isn't such feature. However, you can create such lines using [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer). Or try to utilize more series (line type) to render that lines. The second solution may be a bit harder if your bars can have different height (to determine where line should start and end).

Comment: This is an older example, for a previous similar question (can't find the question now...) : http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/onptrtxg/3/  you have to tweak the x values for the line series to make it work properly - it's a somewhat manual process